# How to approximate distance traveled on Bezier Spline

Tags: unity-game-engine, bezier, spline

I'm working on a game that mixes 3D and 2D gameplay. For 2D, the character can move along a bezier spline, side-scroller style. He is not, however, entirely stuck to the path as he can jump and do air dashes. That said, a problem comes up when trying to get the current position and tangent to use on the spline.
If the movement was entirely on the ground, simply adding the speed to the distance traveled would work however it is possible to skip entire parts of the spline thus rendering the whole method useless.
In the picture below, if the character wall jumps his way through to the upper platform he can jump off and skip the whole pipe segment thus traveling a shorter distance.
Of course, I tried just using the closest point on the spline but that's not reliable in figure 8 splines or this same situation even.

I would be so grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

(note: to keep the player aligned to the spline I get the position on the spline by distance and lerp his position there while keeping his Y untouched )

[image]

Comment: your spline .. is it purely mathematical or does it e.g. have some collider on it? Meaning: Could you use a raycast downwards?

Comment: that's what I came up with, however most of the splines I'm using are imported from an XML file and end up having incorrect normals so I can't generate a good mesh.
I could fix them, but that would take so much time and I'm on a deadline.

So yea a purely mathematical solution is what I'm trying to achieve if possible

Comment: I don't see any code, so... can you update your post to explain _what kind of spline_ you are actually using, with an [MCVE] for _just_ that path across a blank screen that shows that for your chosen `t` value, you get the completely wrong screen coordinate?